# SD Card Locked Error on camera

Tags: sd-card, format

I have a Canon camera. Last week after recording some movies, it took so long to process, so I got bored, and unplugged its batteries :D Then I turned it on, it said "Memory Locked".

I inserted the SD Card into laptop, it's fine. I can copy the pictures easily. But the SD card has been write-protected.

I tried formatting the SD Card, but windows says it's write-protected.

I tried diskpart from command prompt to clear its read-only attribute. It did it. But again I couldn't format it.

Also, the small lock switch on the side of the SD Card is NOT locked.

What's the problem !?

Comment: You likely triggered the firmware write protect, which will kick in if it detects a write error, to protect the existing data. It's pretty much irreversible. Bin it & buy a new one.

Comment: @Tetsujin , You mean, buy a new SD card !? Are there any suggestions to correct this !?

Comment: not if it's firmware locked.

Comment: @Tetsujin , thanks for your comments. How can I make sure if it's firmware locked or not ?

Comment: Try formatting it in several different devices. If they all fail, that's your most likely reason.